# Power BI REST API: Import data

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to import data from Power BI dataset? As CSV, JSON etc.

I tried to send HTTP GET to *https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/datasets/{dataset_id}/table/{table_name}/rows* but server returned 404 error code.

Thanks!

Comment: i have the same problem .  https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/datasets/{dataset_id}/table/{table_name}/row    give me this response :  {"error":{"code":"ItemNotFound","message":"Dataset 16947034-585f-4495-85d0-aef6cf0623c3 is not Push API dataset."}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not supported :).  It's a good item to submit as a feature request here: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi

Appreciate your using Power BI,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com